# I do not know how to get my mic to work on my Mac OS X

Tags: mac, microphone, mute

I have had this Mac for 4 1/2 years.  I have never been able to figure out how to get it to register/record my voice.  I cannot figure out how to use Skype.  Skype tells me my mic is muted.  However, I cannot even get my mic to register when I am right in my system preferences.

Can anybody help?

OS X 10.5.8

Answer (score 0):

Something to keep in mind is you must be using a powered mic on many Macs. Unlike many Windows' PCs, you must have a mic that plugs into USB. Simply putting the mic jack inside the port will usually not work.

Try finding a USB mic, or one that says it is powered.

Good luck!

Comment: I can't confirm this. My Macs have always worked with "normal" unpowered microphones.

Comment: @slhck, What Mac do you have? I a Mac Mini and it did not work with unpowered microphones. It may just be Mac Mini's, I don't know for sure.

Comment: MacBooks and MacBook Pros – I haven't tried the Minis yet, will give it a shot tomorrow at work.

Comment: @slhck, Okay, mine is a 2011, but I would assume older versions work the same. Let me know what you find out, however I might get mad that I bought a whole new microphone for nothing. :(